# Android 4.2 9-patch background drawn differently than older OS versions

Tags: android, nine-patch, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-drawable

I have a Nexus 7 with Android 4.2.1 and I noticed in my app the background image I am using for some linear layouts is drawn incorrectly. With other devices with older versions of the Android OS the 9-patch background is drawn correctly but with this device the border line is stretched when it should not be stretched.

Correct (Evo 4G v2.3.5):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhKLt.png

Incorrect (N7 v4.2.1):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v70w1.png

Any idea what is causing this? If not, is there any other way to get the black borders on these views without using 9-patch images?

*edit*

9-patch file:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIs74.png

9-patch in editor tool:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJjUL.png

layout xml section using it (leftbordergraybkg):

```
<LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/Measurements"
 android:layout_width="0px"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_weight="50"
 android:background="@drawable/leftbordergraybkg"
 android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: Please post the nine-patch and the layout file where it is being applied.

Comment: most likely, it is because your 9 patches are being resized. It is recommended to use at least 2 pixels patches.

Comment: Please see my edit, I added the 9-patch itself and the image of it in the editor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of black pixels showing scalable area are too close to image's border. That's why in higher pixel density 9-patch file scales up and scale piece of border.

See example which will not have such problem.

[image]

Comment: So I should use a larger 9-patch file? The black border on the image is right next to the 1-pixel wide scale section of the 9-patch... can't avoid that to do what I want I don't think. I want a left black border 1 pixel wide that scales vertically and I want everything else to be a solid color.

Comment: @CHollman82: You probably need either multiple versions of the nine-patch for different densities, or to move the nine-patch into `res/drawable-nodpi/`, which should prevent density-based automatic scaling.

Comment: You guys are correct, I made a larger 9-patch for the xhdpi folder and this fixed the problem. Thanks to everyone who replied!