# 9-patch drawable shows different on android 2.+ and 4.+

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have selector for list which is based on 9-patch drawable but it looks different on android 2.+ and 4+ android based devices (LG Optimus Sol E730, Nexus 4, HTC One V):
Result for android 2+

[image]

Result for android 4+

[image]

Here is code of selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/row_widget_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/row_widget_selected" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/row_widget_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/row_widget"/>

</selector>
```

Use of selector:

```
 <com.ssbs.sw.SWE.widget.SpinnerWidget
    android:id="@+id/dialog_outlet_task_edit_spinner_type"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?listWidgetSelector"
```

And selector 9-patch drawable [image]

**Q:** As you can see the same selector looks different on android 4+, it is a gradient why is it so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android 4.2 9-patch background drawn differently than older OS versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767012/android-4-2-9-patch-background-drawn-differently-than-older-os-versions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer on my question here [Android 4.2 9-patch background drawn differently than older OS versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13767129/1307690)

The easiest way to solve it is to follow the @CommonsWare [proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767012/android-4-2-9-patch-background-drawn-differently-than-older-os-versions#comment18925573_13767129)  and move all my drawable to `res/drawable-nodpi/` folder